# How to re-download OS X Lion from 10.6.8

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I purchased OS X 10.7 lion about two years ago, and installed it on my Mac running 10.6.8.

A couple of hours ago I re-formatted my computer and re-installed Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard from the original DVD installer. Now I want to go to the App Store and re-download the OS X Lion installer, to upgrade my system to Lion.

The problem is that when I go to App Store and try to download the OS X 10.7 Lion installer, it reloads the same page and nothing happens.

[image: Screen shot]

I tried to delete the App store cache and re-install, but it did not work.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: When you re-installed OS X 10.6, are you sure that you ran Software Update and installed *all* of Apple's updates and patches to 10.6.x, *before* you tried to download the OS X Lion installer? Check again.

Comment: Same problem here. When you click "OS X Lion", you get a message: "Item Not Available", "The item you've requested is not currently available in the UK store"

Comment: How thorough was your re-formatting? Did you wipe out the [recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) as well?

Answer (score 1):

When a new OS X is released, it isn't no longer possible to download the previous version(s).

Apple has however now with the release of OS X Mavericks (10.9) again opened up for re-download of Lion and Mountain Lion *(if previously purchased)* - or to purchase the two OS's for a price of $19.99 each.

[OS X Lion (10.7)](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion)

[OS X Mountain Lion (10.8)](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 0):

Try signing out of the App Store, restarting your Mac, then signing back into the Store.  I've seen this happen with other purchases.